# gradle keeps crashing, tried deleting gradle folders already,even tried reinstalling all my IDEs including java,flutter etc

Tags: gradle, ide, flutter

im using the default flutter app

error apears on vs code intellij and android studio

using 8 GB ram laptop

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    [√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

> e:\b\build\slave\windows_engine\build\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\thread_pool.cc:
>   341: error: Could not start worker thread: result = 22. Dumping native
>   stack trace for thread 1ed0   [0x00007ff6205f5a0b] Unknown symbol
>   [0x00007ff6205f5a0b] Unknown symbol
>   -- End of DumpStackTrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle was downloading pgks with each launch try, some were unreachable, probably my current location issues,
anyway finally it came through - it took a lot of time though.